Mathematica Player 13.3 dynamic content issue
I am developping an application under mathematica 13 and want other users without Mathematica licence to access it using the Player for notebook version 13.3 (free to download). However, while everything works fine using the Mathematica 13, when saving the outcome (the application) as a notebook and opening it using the player (version 13.3), the button I am creating doesn't work.
Additionaly, when saving the applicatio nas a cdf and opening it using the cdf player version 11 ,then everything works fine !
Here is the code I am using :
dataNamesNEWV2 = 
  Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "dataNamesNEWV2.csv"}], 
   "CSV"];
countries30EADs = {\!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<AR\>\"",
"\"ARGENTINA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "ARGENTINA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<AT\>\"",
"\"AUSTRIA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "AUSTRIA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<AU\>\"",
"\"AUSTRALIA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "AUSTRALIA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<BE\>\"",
"\"BELGIUM\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "BELGIUM", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<BG\>\"",
"\"BULGARIA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "BULGARIA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<BR\>\"",
"\"BRAZIL\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "BRAZIL", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<CA\>\"",
"\"CANADA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "CANADA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<CH\>\"",
"\"SWITZERLAND\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "SWITZERLAND", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<CL\>\"",
"\"CHILE\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "CHILE", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<CN\>\"",
"\"CHINA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "CHINA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<CY\>\"",
"\"CYPRUS\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "CYPRUS", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<CZ\>\"",
"\"CZECH REPUBLIC\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "CZECH REPUBLIC", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<DE\>\"",
"\"GERMANY\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "GERMANY", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<DK\>\"",
"\"DENMARK\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "DENMARK", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<EE\>\"",
"\"ESTONIA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "ESTONIA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<ES\>\"",
"\"SPAIN\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "SPAIN", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<FI\>\"",
"\"FINLAND\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "FINLAND", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<FR\>\"",
"\"FRANCE\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "FRANCE", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<GB\>\"",
"\"UNITED KINGDOM\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "UNITED KINGDOM", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<GR\>\"",
"\"GREECE\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "GREECE", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<HK\>\"",
"\"HONG KONG\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "HONG KONG", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<HR\>\"",
"\"CROATIA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "CROATIA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<HU\>\"",
"\"HUNGARY\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "HUNGARY", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<IE\>\"",
"\"IRELAND\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "IRELAND", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<IT\>\"",
"\"ITALY\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "ITALY", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<JP\>\"",
"\"JAPAN\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "JAPAN", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<KR\>\"",
"\"KOREA, REPUBLIC OF\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "KOREA, REPUBLIC OF", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<LU\>\"",
"\"LUXEMBOURG\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "LUXEMBOURG", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<LT\>\"",
"\"LITHUANIA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "LITHUANIA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<LV\>\"",
"\"LATVIA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "LATVIA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<MT\>\"",
"\"MALTA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "MALTA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<MX\>\"",
"\"MEXICO\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "MEXICO", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<NL\>\"",
"\"NETHERLANDS\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "NETHERLANDS", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<NO\>\"",
"\"NORWAY\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "NORWAY", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<PE\>\"",
"\"PERU\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "PERU", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<PL\>\"",
"\"POLAND\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "POLAND", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<PT\>\"",
"\"PORTUGAL\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "PORTUGAL", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<RO\>\"",
"\"ROMANIA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "ROMANIA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<RU\>\"",
"\"RUSSIAN FEDERATION\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "RUSSIAN FEDERATION", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<SE\>\"",
"\"SWEDEN\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "SWEDEN", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<SG\>\"",
"\"SINGAPORE\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "SINGAPORE", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<SI\>\"",
"\"SLOVENIA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "SLOVENIA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<SK\>\"",
"\"SLOVAKIA\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "SLOVAKIA", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<TR\>\"",
"\"TURKEY\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "TURKEY", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<US\>\"",
"\"UNITED STATES\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "UNITED STATES", "Tooltip"]& ]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
TooltipBox["\"\<ac\>\"",
"\"Aggregation of non relevant countries\"",
TooltipStyle->"TextStyling"],
Annotation[#, "Aggregation of non relevant countries", 
       "Tooltip"]& ]\)};
fieldsdataNames = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "Country", "7", "8", "9", 
   "10", "11", "Reception Date", "13", "14", "15", "16"};
dates = {"Jun2016", "Sep2016", "Dec2016", "Mar2017", "Jun2017", 
   "Sep2017", "Dec2017", "Mar2018", "Jun2018", "Sep2018", "Dec2018", 
   "Mar2019", "Jun2019", "Sep2019", "Dec2019", "Mar2020", "Jun2020", 
   "Sep2020", "Dec2020", "Mar2021", "Jun2021", "Sep2021", "Dec2021", 
   "Mar2022", "Jun2022", "Sep2022", "Dec2022", "Mar2023", "Jun2023", 
   "Sep2023"};
NEWfButtonLables7p1[d_, field_, selecteddata_, source_] := 
 Button[field, 
  CreateDocument[{"", 
    OpenerView[{TextCell["Distribution by " <> field, "Section", 
       Darker[Red, 0.5`], Bold, 14], 
      Column[{"", 
        TextCell[
         Manipulate[
          Module[{pos, cases, cases0, cases1, sortedValues, values, 
            freq, freq0, labelsf},
           pos = Position[fieldsdataNames, field][[1, 1]];
           
           cases = 
            DeleteDuplicates[
             values = Transpose[dataNamesNEWV2][[pos]]]; 
           freq = Table[
             Length[Select[values, #1 == val &]], {val, cases}]; 
           sortedValues = 
            SortBy[Transpose[{cases, freq}], 
             If[rankBy == "Frequency", #1[[2]], #1[[1]]] &]; 
           cases1 = Transpose[sortedValues][[1]]; 
           freq0 = Transpose[sortedValues][[2]]; 
           Which[field == "Country", 
            cases0 = 
             countries30EADs[[
              Flatten[(Position[(ToLowerCase[#1[[2]]] &) /@ 
                    countries30EADs, ToLowerCase[#1]] &) /@ cases1]]],
             field == "Reception Date", 
            cases0 = (StringDrop[#1, -6] &) /@ cases1, True, 
            cases0 = cases1];
           
           labelsf = 
            MapThread[Row[{#1, "(", #2, ")"}] &, {cases0, freq0}]; 
           If[field === "Reception Date", 
            DateHistogram[({ToExpression[StringTake[#1, {7, 10}]], 
                 ToExpression[StringTake[#1, {4, 5}]], 
                 ToExpression[StringTake[#1, {1, 2}]]} &) /@ values, 
             "Day", FrameLabel -> {"Number of data samples", 
               "Date of reception"}, ChartLabels -> Automatic, 
             DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", "\n", "Day"}, 
             Frame -> True, ImageSize -> {1200, 500}], 
            PieChart[freq0, 
             ChartLabels -> Placed[labelsf, "RadialCallout"], 
             ImageSize -> Medium, 
             ChartBaseStyle -> {LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, 
                   "RadialCallout"] &)}]]], {rankBy, {"Frequency", 
            "Case"}}], 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", "Output"]}]}, 
     True], ""},(*Saveable\[Rule]askSaveDocs,*)
   WindowElements -> {"StatusArea", "MagnificationPopUp"}, 
   WindowTitle -> "Title", WindowSize -> All, 
   WindowStatusArea -> DateString[], ImageSize -> Full], 
  Appearance -> "Frameless", FrameMargins -> -3.5`]
nbobj = CreateDocument[
  Manipulate[DynamicModule[{allNames},
    allNames = "Country";
    
    DynamicModule[{selecteddata = {}},
     Column[{
       NEWfButtonLables7p1[30, fieldsdataNames[[6]], selecteddata, 
        "Based on a specific selection in 7.1"],
       Dynamic[selecteddata]
       }],
     InheritScope -> True
     ]],
   Initialization :> (Null), SaveDefinitions -> True, 
   TrackedSymbols :> True, SynchronousUpdating -> False]]
CDFDeploy[
 File[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
    "DeployedAppMini_V3.cdf"}]], nbobj]`

When trying to open it using the notebook player version 13.3 and clicking on the button I have this error :
PieChart[Transpose[dataNamesNEWV2][[{}[[1, 1]]]], 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[MapThread[
    Row[{#1, "(", #2, ")"}] &, {countries30EADs[[
      Table[(Position[(ToLowerCase[#1[[2]]] &) /@ countries30EADs, 
           ToLowerCase[#1]] &)[
        Length[Select[
          values$3235, #1 == 
            val &]]], (Position[(ToLowerCase[#1[[2]]] &) /@ 
            countries30EADs, ToLowerCase[#1]] &)[{val, 
         Transpose[dataNamesNEWV2][[{}[[1, 1]]]]}]]]], 
     Transpose[dataNamesNEWV2][[{}[[1, 1]]]]}], "RadialCallout"], 
 ImageSize -> Medium, 
 ChartBaseStyle -> {LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, 
       "RadialCallout"] &)}]

I expected the version 13.3 of the player to be able to execute my code and retrieve the data correctly but it seems that it is not able to acces the data through dynamic elements.

Please provide a sample value for dataNamesNEWV2 so that we can run the code. Always try to include all code needed to reproduce the issue and at the same time try to make the code as small as possible. Also, for WL issues, consider asking at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ where you will have many more views.
